# How to use TeeChart with Jquery to dynamically update a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, activex, teechart

I currently use TeeChart within Classic ASP to create charts as images on the server.  What I'm trying to do now, is to update a chart based on user selection without refreshing the whole page.

Within the global.asa file I have;

```
<!--METADATA NAME="TeeChart Pro v2012 ActiveX Control" TYPE="TypeLib" UUID="{5006E56D-FEDE-4C64-9CC2-78C320929406}"-->
```

I think I need to do an Object within the ASP, such as

```
<OBJECT
id="TChart1" 
width="400" 
height="268" 
type="application/x-oleobject" 
hspace="0"
vspace="0" 
classid="CLSID:5006E56D-FEDE-4C64-9CC2-78C320929406"
codebase="http://locahost/TeeChart/Teechart2012.cab#Version=V2">
</OBJECT>
```

Within the  $(document).ready(function () event, I'm trying to execute

```
TChart1.Import.LoadFromURL("http://localhost/testscripts/ExportChart.asp");
```

I'm getting an error from the Javascript of :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'LoadFromURL' of undefined
```

So, I have a few questions.

1. How do execute the TChart1.Import.LoadFromURL?
2. How can I find out the and codebase of my object?
3. Is this the best method of creating the chart without creating an image locally on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: What is TChart1? `console.log(TChart1);`

Comment: TChart1 is the name of the object created within the ASP server side code.